# Alternative to webkit-playsinline for Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, safari

I have a tool (Articulate Storyline) that generates interactive videos embedded into web pages. When opening from mobile devices or from Safari, the interaction doesn't work. I found that the attribute `webkit-playsinline` could solve my issue, but it works on the video tag, not on the object tag (which is the one being generated by my tool. 
I have a similar issue with Cordova: my hybrid app for iOS is not interactive, while the one for Android is.
Is there a way I can force the same behavior on the object tag (or in its containing iframe tag)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with an iFrame tag, but I do believe it is possible in a Cordova application.  In the Cordova settings for your webview, set `AllowInlineMediaPlayback` to `YES` and `MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to `NO`.  I don't know too much about Cordova applications, but I do know that these keys map to the `UIWebView` `allowInlineMediaPlayback` and `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` properties, which protect against automatic video playback in a webview.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the documentation (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/), "for this to work, add the webkit-playsinline attribute to any <video> elements".